# UITableView reloadData best practice

Tags: ios, uitableview

When is the best time to call [reloadData] on a UITableView?  viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?   If a view is unloaded, will the underlying tableview be unloaded as well?

The reason I am asking is due to some behavior I am seeing.  Let's say a view is asked to reload its datasource, but is deallocated before it can finish.  A scenario would be with a UITabBarController and navigating to a different view than the ViewController being selected.  So what happens is that viewWillAppear gets called, but viewDidAppear does not (since I navigated away).

As a result, the ViewController gets deallocated (along with its model data), but if I am calling reloadData in viewWillAppear, the "cellForRow", and "numberOfRows" methods are invoked which causes a "deallocated instance" error.  Does that make sense?  Do you normally put in code that checks for nil if the model can be changed anytime the view is requested to appear?

Comment: It really kind of depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I guess this kind of leads into some behavior I am seeing with iOS.  Let's say your model data can change each time a view appears (customer data stored into a session on the client).

Comment: What exactly is deallocated? The table view wouldn't normally be removed from memory just because you navigated to another tab, and the view controller itself wouldn't get deallocated just because it's view was unloaded. What crash are you seeing?

Comment: Basically, the ViewController is being popped off the navigation stack, but is never being displayed.  It gets deallocated, which deallocates the models.  In this scenario, viewWillAppear gets called along with reloadData; however, viewDidAppear does not get called.  So what happens is 1) reloadData 2) dealloc 3) cellForRowAtIndex which references the deallocated model.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the table once the view has loaded, it allows for all of the UIObjects to be created before messing with them. Not sure, but I believe the table is automatically unloaded with the superview.

Take a look at this question>>>
[Objective C - Correct way to empty and reload UITableViewController with NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708992/objective-c-correct-way-to-empty-and-reload-uitableviewcontroller-with-nsmutab/9709432#9709432)

Comment: That's OK if the data does not change between loads, but what happens when the data can change.  Let's say it's model data that is changed in another view.

Answer (score 0):

before you get the datasource from server or anywhere, you can display the tableview with a blankcell(a cell that you can draw sth like 404 web page) ,  when you get the data, then reload the tableview.
remember to set number of cell to 1 for the blankcell